# Trying to find the an element with span id in selenium and C# but getting error element not found

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click an element located in menu bar and click on it but I was getting an error as

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

HTML:

```
<div id="et_top_search">
    <span id="et_search_icon"/>
</div>
```

C# code:

```
_driver.FindElementByXPath(".//span[@id='et_search_icon']").Click();
```

Comment: Is there another step for the specified JavaScript element to become visible? You can't click on an element until it is loaded onto the page

Comment: I think element is visible on the page because I also add explicit wait for the but still no luck.

Comment: An element can still be loaded but not be visible to the browser, think about how you as a user would get to and click on the element, you need to recreate that process

Answer (score 0):

You have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(".//span[@id='et_search_icon']"))).Click();
```

Comment: Still no luck. Let me provide the url of the website www.ultimateqa.com.